# How should I find the correct subject in (who) questions?

Tags: grammar, subjects

I am confused to ascertain the correct subject in the questions, look at the following sentences:

`Who are those men?
     (v) (---s---)`

`Who is  at the door?
 (s) (v)`

The form of questions is the same, I cannot understand what caused the difference.

Comment: @BillJ: No it's not. I think it's related to subject and object questions. take a look at: https://books.google.com/books?id=stmGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=%22Who+are+those+men%22+%22Who+is++at+the+door%22&source=bl&ots=TU5-y3rmbK&sig=ACfU3U0jaoMOuJGYoV66LaA8SZt05-JjBA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk69q2qb3nAhUNuaQKHRB7BGcQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Who%20are%20those%20men%22%20%22Who%20is%20%20at%20the%20door%22&f=false

Comment: There are no objects in either example.

Comment: @BillJ: As far as I have just understood, probably, the first one asks about the subject of the sentence, and the second one asks about the object of the sentence.

Comment: In the second example the preposition phrase "at the door" is locative **complement** of "is", not object.

Comment: ***God** knows!, **No-one** knows, **Who** knows?* They all look like candidates for "subject" if you think that category is useful here. Which I don't.

Answer (score 1):

I think "those men" is not a subject but the object of the sentence. In both sentences you try to find out the subjects using nouns or adverbs.

Comment: @BillJ: No it's a subject, I think it is a subject question, take a look at https://books.google.com/books?id=stmGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=%22Who+are+those+men%22+%22Who+is++at+the+door%22&source=bl&ots=TU5-y3rmbK&sig=ACfU3U0jaoMOuJGYoV66LaA8SZt05-JjBA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk69q2qb3nAhUNuaQKHRB7BGcQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Who%20are%20those%20men%22%20%22Who%20is%20%20at%20the%20door%22&f=false

Comment: @BillJ I think as far as I understood that "those men" is subject of the question, which means it looks for the subject but it is the object of the sentence in terms of parts of speech.

Comment: There is no transitive verb and thus no object in either example. It follows that in the second example, the preposition phrase "at the door" is not an object, but a locative **complement** that is subject oriented.